# How to create thumbnail carousel with image previews in Slick.js?

Tags: javascript, slick.js

I want to preview image after the click to a thumbnail in a slideshow. It also appears image previews in Slick.js. You can [see more at here.](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

Like this:

[image: capture]

When a user clicks a thumbnail it will show this image preview.

I watch all demo of Slick but not found any example like this.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use Slider Syncing as given [here](http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```
$('.slider-for').slick({
  slidesToShow: 1,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  arrows: false,
  fade: true,
  asNavFor: '.slider-nav'
});
$('.slider-nav').slick({
  slidesToShow: 3,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  asNavFor: '.slider-for',
  dots: true,
  centerMode: true,
  focusOnSelect: true
});
```

It looks like:
[image]

Comment: That great. I really don't see this until your comment. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 13):

I use `jQuery index()` plus `Slick slickGoTo method`.
Fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/beluluk/uh8bpokb/

Html:

```
<div class='slider'>
  <div>Slide 1</div>
  <div>Slide 2</div>
  <div>Slide 3</div>
  <div>Slide 4</div>
  <div>Slide 5</div>
</div>

<div class='slider-nav'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
  <div>5</div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
//Slick slider initialize
$('.slider').slick({
  arrows:false, dots: false, infinite:true, speed:500,
  autoplay:true, autoplaySpeed: 3000, slidesToShow:1, slidesToScroll:1
});
//On click of slider-nav childern,
//Slick slider navigate to the respective index.
$('.slider-nav > div').click(function() {
    $('.slider').slick('slickGoTo',$(this).index());
})
```

CSS Beautification:

```
/*Slider*/
.slider > div {
  display:block; width:100%; padding: 50px 0;
  background: #FF0;
  text-align: center; font-size: 2em;
}

/* Navigation */
.slider-nav { text-align: center; }
.slider-nav > div {
  display:inline-block;
  width:30px; height: 30px; margin: 0 5px; padding: 3px 0;
  text-align: center; font-size:2em;
  background: #FC0; cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This makes sense if they number of slides is changing, instead of using Slide Syncing.